# Django API status code 200 but data is not updating in Database

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, pymongo

I am Using Django framework to create an Update-API. I have used Pymongo library, I am making a POST request from my react app using Axios, The response shows a status code of 200, but there is no change in the database.

**Points to Note:**
*The API works fine with POSTMAN.
*I have written the same API in flask which works well.
* I am working with other POST requests too in Django like /signup which works well.[image]

Comment: When you mention the API works fine, are you meaning that your data is updating to the database?

Comment: Yes, The Data is updating to the database.

Comment: Please update you post with actual code instead of it's image.